# Download, count and discard HTTP response bytes without reading or decypting them

Tags: http, go, ssl, io, buffer

I'm making an HTTP GET request for a large payload and counting the bytes as I read/download them with:

`bufio.NewReader(resp.Body).Discard(128 * 1024)`

My goal is to download and count the bytes from the response but I don't actually care about the content; therefore, to speed up the program, I don't want to do the TLS decryption that happens with `io.Read`.

I just want to download and count the raw encrypted bytes without reading or decrypting them.

You can see in the source code of `bufio.Discard` that it still reads the bytes into the buffer using an `io.Reader`.

- https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/bufio/bufio.go#L175
- https://github.com/golang/go/blob/1811aeae66bee899317403c92c83b56673919775/src/bufio/bufio.go#L101

Is there a way to avoid doing this?

Comment: If the content is encrypted, you won't be able to get the exact length of the content without decrypting it due to things like padding and compression. Not sure if this matters to you.

Comment: Do you need an accurate total for the payload? Since you can't inspect what's in the TLS channel without decrypting it, you can only get the total bytes read for the connection, or a portion of the bytes after the transfer has started.

Answer (score 2):

Well, discarding you're talking about happens *above* TLS—on the bytes which are shoveled *in* the tunnel provided by TLS.

So to skip some amount of bytes without decrypting them you clearly need to break the abstraction: in the code which works above TLS, you want to tell the TLS layer "skip whatever number of bytes you need so that in the result we've skipped N bytes of plaintext, and then return control to me".

While this appears to be doable in theory, you will hardly be able to do that using `net/http` alone. Supposedly you'd need to take the TLS package and implement a minimal (but complete) parser to HTTP method line and the header.

Also I'm not absolutely sure you can do that "skip whatever number of bytes you need so that in the result we've skipped N bytes of plaintext" with TLS in all possible cases, as this presupposes N bytes of plaintext always result in M bytes of cyphertext, and I'm not sure it's always the case (Hymns for Disco appears to point out some clear suspects).